# How to use default SES smtp_mail_from with MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, airflow, amazon-ses, mwaa

#### Problem

I'm using [Amazon MWAA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/what-is-mwaa.html) along with [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to send logs when an **airflow** task fails. The problem is that from the `MWAA panel > airflow-instance > Settings > Airflow configuration options` I can't set up the `smtp.smtp_mail_from` attribute so it picks up the **default** one from amazon, as mentioned here:

> By default, messages that you send through Amazon SES use a subdomain
> of amazonses.com as the MAIL FROM domain. Sender Policy Framework
> (SPF) authentication successfully validates these messages because the
> default MAIL FROM domain matches the application that sent the email—
> in this case, Amazon SES. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/mail-from.html#mail-from-overview)

So when I send emails I get the following **error**:

```
ERROR - (501, b'Invalid MAIL FROM address provided', 'notification.us-east-1.amazonses.com')
```

This is because of my following variables values:

[image]

#### Question

How can I specify `smtp_mail_from` so that it picks the default from amazon and no custom **MAIL FROM domain** is needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the field 'smtp_mail_from' expects a SES-verified email address as 'user.address@domain.com'.